# Generated current in a \$3\times450\$ VAC \$60\$ Hz \$1150\$ kVA generator

Tags: power, current, frequency, generator, three-phase

Let's say I've a \$3\times450\$ VAC \$60\$ Hz \$1150\$ kVA generator. How much current will there be generated when it runs at maximum capacity?

---

**MY WORK:**

The total Active power over a three-fase system is given by:

$$P=\sqrt{3}UI\cos\varphi\tag1$$

Where \$U\$ is the line voltage and \$I\$ is the line current.

The total Reactive power is given by:

$$Q=\sqrt{3}UI\sin\varphi\tag2$$

Where \$U\$ is the line voltage and \$I\$ is the line current.

The total Complex power is given by:

$$S=\sqrt{3}UI\tag3$$

Where \$U\$ is the line voltage and \$I\$ is the line current.

So, I know that:

$$1150\times1000=\sqrt{3}UI\tag3$$

> But what is the line voltage? Is it \$450\$ volts? So, then we get: \$1150\times1000=\sqrt{3}\times450I\$ which give that the line current equals \$I=\frac{1150\times1000}{\sqrt{3}\times450}\approx1475.5\$ A.

Comment: Huh, what?  "Well, also that is not possible, because I get 3740 A and that current is two times bigger than the fuse that is used!" What fuse? Is this real or homework?

Comment: @Tyler It is a real schematic for a project I'm working on

Comment: The fuse does not need to be sized for the maximum that the system can produce.

Comment: Anyone messing around with MW power levels shouldn't have to ask here.  Conversely, anyone asking here shouldn't be messing with MW power levels.

Comment: If 450 VAC is the line-to-line rms voltage (which is the usual convention) then the phase current rms is 1475 A.

Comment: Where did you get that generator. Commercial generators typically come in these voltages: 
Single-Phase
• 120
• 240
• 120/240 

3-Phase
• 208
• 120/208
• 240
• 480 (the most common voltage for industrial gensets)
• 277/480
• 600 (mainly for areas in Canada)
• 4160 Volt

Comment: It is very common in shipping industry. Most of the "non special" vessels have delta insulated 3phase 450V line to line 60Hz generators. if i had to take a guess it would be around 600 000 generators in use today. Usually rated in KW for the engineers convenience as prime mover is HFO burning Diesel generator. Nameplate of one of these units that i have onboard says "MAIN GENERATOR (AC450V 750KW 1203A 3fi 60Hz)"

Answer (score 1):

Power engineers always use line-to-line rms when describing the voltage rating of three phase equipment.

So, in your case that is 450 V rms line-to-line.  Your answer is correct (1,475 A).

Answer (score -1):

There is a some information in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase) of Wikipedia.

Let \$V\$ be the RMS voltage between each of the phases and the neutral, and
\$V_p\$ be its amplitude: \$V_p = \sqrt{2}V\$.

Let \$U\$ be the RMS voltage between two phases, and \$U_p\$ be its amplitude:

\$U = \sqrt{3}V\$, \$U_p = \sqrt{2}U\$.

Finally, let \$P = 1150 kVA\$ be the apparent total power available from the generator: it is the sum of the powers of each dipole.

It is unclear in the question whose of these voltages is meant by 450V AC. I suppose here that that this is RMS voltage between the phases and the neutral, that is \$V\$: \$V = 450\$.

Next, the question of "how much current it runs" is ill-posed. A current flows through two terminals, but here there are 4 terminals.
Is it the current flowing through the phase and the neutral? the current flowing through 2 phases (if connected), the total current flowing through the terminals in a balanced "Delta" configuration? or the total current flowing through the terminals in a balanced "Wye" configuration? This need be specified, because the answer is different in each case.

Assuming for example you demand the maximal current between two phases:
Then

\$I_{max}\ (rms) = P / U\$, which is the value you have to use for your "fuse" between 2 phases. The maximum current amplitude is \$ \sqrt{2}P/U\$

If you demand the maximal current between a phase and the neutral, then
\$I_{max}\ (rms) = P / V\$ and the maximum amplitude is \$\sqrt{2}P/V\$.

The other cases are processed similarly.

Comment: Well, this is not true. Because the voltage and current are always the RMS ones (not the maximum/amplitude). P is in Watt (W) not in VA. Since I only not the things (of the generator) that are listed in my first line of the question I can not use anything about the impedance. Next the current is big and can never be as low as \$3.74\$ A!!!

Comment: Well, also that is not possible, because I get \$3740\$ A and that current is two times bigger than the fuse that is used!

Comment: What is wrong, when I use the formula: $$\text{S}=\sqrt{3}\cdot\text{U}\cdot\text{I}$$ Where \$\text{U}\$ is the effective line voltage and \$\text{I}\$ is the effective line current? Or I can write $$\text{S}=\sqrt{3}\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{U}}}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{I}}}{\sqrt{2}}=$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot\hat{\text{U}}\cdot\hat{\text{I}}$$

Comment: My book tells me the formula's I used!

Comment: Where did you get that?

Comment: asdasdw, I suggest you delete the comments related to my previous answer that I've replaced by this new one. They are no more relevant.

Comment: What does "power between phase and neutral" mean? In my universe you can measure voltages between two nodes in a network but not power. And power is usually assigned one of the letters P, Q or S as asdasdw did and not V or U. It seems as if you have mixed up some things here.

Comment: Yeah. There was a typo: "power" in place of "voltage" near the beginning, as could have been understood from the sequel (" I suppose here that that this is RMS voltage between the phases and the neutral, that is V etc."). I've corrected the typos.